# How to grab onto a ledge without climbing up

Tags: batman-arkham-city, batman-arkham-origins

In Batman Arkham Origins (and AC incidentally), if I try to grapple onto a ledge from below (in order to silent-kill a guard), about half the time I'll hang from the ledge and the other half of the time I'll end up automatically climbing up, and therefore exposing myself to the guards.

Is there a way to grapple onto a ledge without climbing all the way up (i.e. hang from the ledge), so I can perform a ledge takedown?

Comment: Pushing the directional stick forward during the grapple would probably be the cause.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Arkham City at least, this is accomplished by holding RB (or the F key if you're using keyboard) instead of tapping it.